# How to convert my JSON to Shapefile?

Tags: python, json

So, after making an API request, I get a JSON response like in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvDyw.jpg.

Basically, I am trying to convert it Shapefile using Python but do I need to convert my JSON to GEOJSON first? Any feedback is appreciated and thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://paulcrickard.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/json-to-shapefile/ can help

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can convert JSON to SHP:
paulcrickard.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/json-to-shapefile